# Is there a way to set transparent background image in XFCE4 terminal?

Tags: bash, xfce, xfce4-terminal

Is it possible to **set a background image with *opacity*** 0.5? Or do I have to use a different terminal emulator? In this case, which one would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. You can only set a black transparent terminal background or and image with full opacity. Use tilda or something else for transparent background image.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible.
Open a terminal, open the menu "Edit>Preferences". Select the "Appearance tab". Change the background box to "Transparent Background". Move the "Opacity slider to 0.50"

[image]

(Theme is [mine](https://www.pling.com/p/1185760/), I don't like flat ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I wanted an image with opacity as a terminal background. Tilda can do this.